# flutter LinearGradient transparent to white overlay

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

I am trying to make a container that fades from transparent to white. I'll put it over stuff so it looks like the content behind is fading away into the whiteness of the background.

When I tried to do this using `LinearGradient` I get this weird grey.

```
Widget body() => Stack(
  children: [
    MyFormWidget(),
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.white])))]);
```

[image: gradient]

What's going on here?

I tried a `ShaderMask` but that only applies to children and I don't want to include the contents of the page as children because I only want this applied to one part of the screen.

How do I make a simple transparent-> white Fad container on top of the stack?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

replaced `Colors.transparent` with `Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)`

Comment: Please don't use answers to summarize your solution. If this is intended to be the selected answer, then write a complete answer. See "[answer]" and its linked pages.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the tip. I think this is better than nothing. Maybe it might help someone someday who thinks, as I did, that `Colors.Transparent` is the same as transparent white, its not.

Comment: That was the solution for my problem! Thanks @MetaStack

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem,
you should use a gradient of different shades of white to make the effect of a fade.

Try this :

```
Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                stops: [
                  0.2,
                  0.5,
                  0.7,
                  0.6,
                ],
                colors: [
                  Colors.transparent,
                  Colors.white10,
                  Colors.white54,
                  Color.fromARGB(190, 255, 255, 255),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

You can change values in